# Summernote is not a function, when creating a Vue Component

Tags: webpack, vue.js, summernote

I`m trying to make a Wrapper for summernote (the ones I found online didn't do exactly what I needed, such as emitting all event).

I`m importing jquery inside webpack.base.conf.js

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
```

Then, inside the component, I'm requiring bootstrap, lang package and some CSS:

```
require('bootstrap');
require('summernote');
require('summernote/dist/summernote.css');
require('summernote/dist/lang/summernote-pt-BR.min.js')

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
```

However, when I get into the render() method, and initialize summernote on the jQuery element, I

> $(...).summernote is not a function

If I try to console.log(summernote), it returns undefined, or even an empty obj.

I have it imported using NPM, as well as jquery, bootstrap...

I had it working before, but I deleted my node_modules folder and installed it again. Maybe I had a dependency that I`m missing now? Because the code itself wasn't changed, only the node_modules folders. But I don't know what I could be missing at this point.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876750/using-summernote-with-vue-js-2