# using summernote with vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, summernote

i want to use summernote in my vue.js 2 spa, and because not all my page using summernote so i make summernote to be a component by adding

```
export default {
    editor_function(){
     //summernote function in summernote.min.js
    }
}
```

and then i just import it in my .vue file that need summernote and call `editor_function` on `mounted()` function but i got error `unknown codemirror` when npm compile my vue project into single app.js file.

so i went into just include summernote.min.js in my index.html and thats mean it will be loaded before vue js spa is started (which is not very ideal since only some page need this plugin, but well i need this to work)

so after that it is working, but now i got no idea how to get ouput data from summernote into vuejs, i am adding v-`model` into `textarea` like this

```
<textarea class="summernote" v-model="content"></textarea>
```

i also tried to make custom input like this but not working

```
<textarea class="summernote" 
          :value="content"
          @input="content = $event.target.value"></textarea>
```

but it just not binded into my v-model content and that's mean when i post the output from summernote/content it will be empty...

so how to make summernote works with vue js 2? i found some package for summernote and vue js but it's works only with old version vue js( v.1 maybe?) and not compatible with vue js 2.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/StefanNeuser/vuejs2-summernote-component), I think it meets your requirement.

Comment: oh i already look into that and its look promising but lack of guide and have no idea how to implement it in my own project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered here since comments are not very good at displaying code.

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <summernote
    name="editor"
    :model="content"
    v-on:change="value => { content = value }"
  ></summernote>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        content: null   
    }
  },
  components: {
    'summernote' : require('./Summernote')
  }
}
</script>
```

I think you can use the [summernote module](https://github.com/StefanNeuser/vuejs2-summernote-component/blob/master/src/Summernote.js) in this way.
I looked into the source code. It's quite simple and short since it's just a wrapper of summernote.

**Update**
I forked the project and changed some code to make it easier to set summernote's configuration and plugins. With [this version](https://github.com/cho0o0/vuejs2-summernote-component), you can pass your configuration as an object prop. 
You can also add a plugin by importing it in html `script` tag.
See sample code below.

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <summernote
    name="editor"
    :model="content"
    v-on:change="value => { content = value }"
    :config="config"
  ></summernote>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        content: null,
        // ↓ It is what the configuration object looks like. ↓
        config: {
            height: 100,
            toolbar: [
                // [groupName, [list of button]]
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['insert', ['gxcode']], // plugin config: summernote-ext-codewrapper
          ],
        }, 
    }
  },
  components: {
    'summernote' : require('./Summernote')
  }
}
</script>
```

I wish you could get my idea. You can also look into the forked project for more information.

Comment: wow it's working.... soo if i want to costumize summernote like if i  want to add sumernote plugin or just choose which button/control that appear in toolbar where should i write that? is it in summernote module? since i see there is height property set in there

Comment: @LaurensiusTony I forked the project to fit your requirement. See my updated answer.

Comment: @choasia I keep getting $.summernote() is not a function. Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: @choasia I have tried your above solution but get a $.summernote() is not a function Error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Luka Have you installed all the dependencies, I tried to run the example and it still works for me.

Comment: @choasia To be honest, I am not sure. I run npm install --save cho0o0/vuejs2-summernote-component and as a reply I got skipping 1 optional dependency fsevents@1.2.4 updated 1 package. So it looks ok to me. In my package.json I have got "dependencies": {
        "ajv": "^6.0.0",
        "codemirror": "^5.39.0",
        "flexslider": "^2.7.1",
        "tether": "^1.4.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.16",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vuejs2-summernote-component": "github:cho0o0/vuejs2-summernote-component"
    }

Comment: @Luka Would you please check whether `dist/index.html` works well for you? As you can see, it requires quite a lot of dependencies. https://github.com/cho0o0/vuejs2-summernote-component/blob/master/index.html#L37-L40

Comment: Hi. I'm using latest vue js 3 cli and I'm trying to implement summer note in one of my component. But its not rendering properly, not able to see any icons. Could you please mention the steps needed to implement summernote in vuejs project created with vue cli 3? Thanks.

Comment: Are you open to dropping an MIT license file in that project? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulCezanne I am totally fine with my part, but please note that the original repository doesn't contain any license information.